# How to print signal names(not descr) in linux

Tags: linux, signals, libc

I need to print signal name in linux by its number, but strsignal(9) return description of signal("Killed") but not name - SIGKILL. Is there any way to get such name, except insert predefined array in sourcecode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of any standard function for it. You could generate a function using a script:

```
echo "#include <signal.h>" |\
  g++ -E -dD -xc++ - |\
  awk '$2~/^SIG[A-Z]/ && $3~/[0-9]+/ { print "case "$2": return \""$2"\";" }' \
  > signal_to_str_cases.inc
```

And then in code:

```
#include <signal.h>

char const* signal_to_str(int signo) {
    switch(signo) {
    #include "signal_to_str_cases.inc"
    default: return "<unknown signo>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeap. Seems like scriptway is only way in linux. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The above scriptway solution is good indeed, however, there is a problem when you have several signals with the same number. In this case code won't compile and will give you an error(s) like "duplicate case value". One way to fix it is not to generate cases for repeated values:

```
echo "#include <signal.h>" |\
    g++ -E -dD -xc++ - |\
    awk '$2~/^SIG[A-Z]/ && $3~/[0-9]+/ && !seen[$3]++ { print "case "$2": return \""$2"\";" }' \
    > signal_to_str_cases.inc
```